# why show error: command failed checkout when npm install?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, npm, clone

[image]

I clone https://github.com/mahdisadeghi74/readium-js-viewer repository but when i install npm show this error

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: git checkout master
npm ERR! error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\M.Sadeghi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-06T12_39_15_548Z-debug.log
```

I Use Git initialisation of this repository readme.me line by line:

git clone --recursive -b BRANCH_NAME https://github.com/readium/readium-js-viewer.git readium-js-viewer (replace "BRANCH_NAME" with e.g. "develop")
cd readium-js-viewer
git submodule update --init --recursive to ensure that the readium-js-viewer chain of dependencies is initialised (readium-js, readium-shared-js)
git checkout BRANCH_NAME && git submodule foreach --recursive "git checkout BRANCH_NAME" (or simply cd inside each repository / submodule, and manually enter the desired branch name: git checkout BRANCH_NAME) Git should automatically track the corresponding branch in the 'origin' remote.
Advanced usage (e.g. TravisCI) - the commands below automate the remote/origin tracking process (this requires a Bash-like shell):

for remote in `git branch -r | grep -v \> | grep -v master`; do git branch --track ${remote#origin/} $remote; done to ensure that all Git 'origin' remotes are tracked by local branches.
git checkout `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short) %(objectname)" 'refs/heads/' | grep $(git rev-parse HEAD) | cut -d " " -f 1` to ensure that Git checks-out actual branch names (as by default Git initializes submodules to match their registered Git SHA1 commit, but in detached HEAD state)
(repeat for each repository / submodule)

Source tree preparation
npm run prepare:all (to perform required preliminary tasks, like patching code before building)
OR: yarn run prepare:yarn:all (to use Yarn instead of NPM for node_module management)
Note that in some cases, administrator rights may be needed in order to install dependencies, because of NPM-related file access permissions (the console log would clearly show the error). Should this be the case, running sudo npm run prepare:all usually solves this.

Note that the above command executes the following:

npm install (to download dependencies defined in package.json ... note that the --production option can be used to avoid downloading development dependencies, for example when testing only the pre-built build-output folder contents)
npm update (to make sure that the dependency tree is up to date)
some additional HTTP requests to the GitHub API in order to check for upstream library updates (wherever Readium uses a forked codebase)